# Rails postgres sql view missing data when creating via migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, postgresql-9.5

I've been speeding up some statistics reports in my rails(4.2.7, postgres 9.5 database) project via creating sql views.

I wrote all code in PGAdmin, checked all data in views. Then I generated migration in my rails project and copied all written sql code to migration.

When I run migration, all views are being created with randomly missing data.

Example:

```
create or replace view revenue_by_date as
  select sum(reward) as reward_coins, count(ot.id) as amount, (sum(reward)::float / substring(value from '---\s''(\d+)''')::bigint) as reward_dollars,
  ot.created_at::date as date
  from offerwall_transactions ot
  inner join settings on var = 'exchange_rate'
  where ot.reward > 1
  group by ot.created_at::date, settings.value;
```

I get reward_dollars data missing.
[image: Query result]

However, when creating via PGA data is ok [image: Normal Query result]

Settings table structure: [image: Settings]

Offerwall transactions table structure: [image: OT]

I have same problems with other views. Some views are created with no data at all.

Where is a mistake?

Comment: `on var = 'exchange_rate'` is not very specific. Will probably yield a carthesian product.

Comment: 'var' is a text column in 'settings'. I'll try to use more specific 'settings.var'.

Comment: But there still is no connection to the `offerwall_transactions` table, you are only restricting on a constant (similar for the WHERE clause)

Comment: Yes, there's no connection from 'settings' to 'offerwall_transactions'. I just need to get 'exchange_rate' field value for calculation. Basically, just `select reward / (select settings.value from settings where settings.var='exchange_rate') from offerwall_transactions`. Join is better in that case, isn't it?

Comment: So, `settings.var` is a candidate key (or PK) for the settings table? BTW: this kind of question cannot be answered without details about the data model (I was assuming a kind of EAV-like structure)

Comment: Added settings table example to question